# How can i get the release notes of a NuGet package with the official SDK in C#

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I need to get the Release Notes stored in the metadata. This code seems to be able to read the metadata, however i dont know how to get to the release notes.

```
using NuGet.Common;
using NuGet.Protocol;
using NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types;
using NuGet.Versioning;


ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;
CancellationToken cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;

SourceCacheContext cache = new SourceCacheContext();
SourceRepository repository = Repository.Factory.GetCoreV3("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");
PackageMetadataResource resource = await repository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>();

IEnumerable<IPackageSearchMetadata> packages = await resource.GetMetadataAsync(
    "Flexygo",
    includePrerelease: true,
    includeUnlisted: false,
    cache,
    logger,
    cancellationToken);
```

i am trying to get a String with the release notes using only the official SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the above using the Library `NuGet.Client`. Install the following library using your Nuget package manager console via the below code :

```
Install-Package NuGet.Client
```

**If not you can alter your own code as per below to print all information extracted :**

```
using NuGet.Common;
using NuGet.Protocol;
using NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;

        SourceCacheContext cache = new SourceCacheContext();
        SourceRepository repository = Repository.Factory.GetCoreV3("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");
        PackageMetadataResource resource = await repository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>();

        IEnumerable<IPackageSearchMetadata> packages = await resource.GetMetadataAsync(
            "Flexygo",
            includePrerelease: true,
            includeUnlisted: false,
            cache,
            logger,
            cancellationToken);


        foreach (var package in packages)
        {
            var packageMetadata = await resource.GetMetadataAsync(package.Identity, cache, logger, cancellationToken);
            var v = await packageMetadata.GetDeprecationMetadataAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Package Metadata: " + packageMetadata.Title.ToString());

            Type t = packageMetadata.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in pi)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " : " + p.GetValue(packageMetadata));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This code does not show the Release Notes

Comment: IPackageSearchMetadata does not have any property called Release Notes. Only available is the ReadmeUrl

Comment: I know, is there any other solutions to this?

Comment: Whatever information which are available is the once that has been exposed by the developer team. As of now for the specified package, this is all the information available. You can check my provided solution for some other package and see if it gives any other useful properties. I have attached a screenshot for your references

Comment: The release notes are in the metadata whatsoever. is it impossible to get?

Comment: @VictorTercerofor the given package alternative metadata is null. You can access all properties via the solution I provided. Please don't forget to mark it as the correct answer and give an upvote for the community.

Comment: NuGet.Client is a super old package that isn't maintained any longer. I'll work on getting it marked as deprecated on nuget.org. For reading & writing packages, now you should use NuGet.Packaging